# Is there a Perl way of doing Quaternion <> Euler angles conversion?

Tags: perl, rotation, quaternions

I've been searching all the land for a Perl algorithm for converting quaternion/quaternation rotations to Euler angle rotations, and vice versa. Like a <10,90,0> (xyz) Euler conversion to a quaternion, and a quaternion back to a simple <x,y,z> Euler. To my surprise, nothing like that seems to exist. Try googling for "use Math::Quaternion", and you'll find no matches (Sic!)

Is nobody doing this kind of conversion?! Or is it truly so complex?! If anyone knows of such module (if it exists), I'd love to hear about it. Thx.

Comment: See also [Math::Quaternion](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JCHIN/Math-Quaternion-0.07/lib/Math/Quaternion.pm), and [Ogre::Quaternion](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SLANNING/Ogre-0.60/Ogre/Quaternion.pm)

Comment: Are you saying Math::Quaternion doesn't exist? That would be [false](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Quaternion). /// If you were saying it doesn't do what you want, then maybe you can use [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL) to implement a solution. (I have no idea what those things you mentioned are.)

Comment: I didn's say Math::Quaternion does not exist, but "Try googling for 'use Math::Quaternion', and you'll find no matches." Aka, can't find any example of someone using it, on the entire Internet (which is really rather bizarre).

Comment: I found this https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1085414 ---https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Quaternion --- https://docs.raku.org/language/math --- https://github.com/Util/Perl6-Math-Quaternion --- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Math%3A%3AQuaternion%22+%22Perl%22&kp=1&t=hk&ia=web --- Hope that helps

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing because you add that bit about googling: `Math::Quaternion` is for doing math using quaternions, it seems there is no open source code using it out there, that is of no concern to anyone. You want to do a conversion, to/from, and not calculations using quaternions and for that you don't need a perl package, it requires some trig equations, which even wikipedia lists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles .

Comment: I'm not a math person. And that whole wiki page, pardon the pun, looks like algebra to me. :) I was hoping somewhere on the net someone was taking a Euler, comverting it in Perl to a quaternion, and then back. Thing is, I only need it, because many game files (ymap in GTA V, or Second Life rotations), use quaternion, and I need to see them in human-readable rotations (Euler). Ogre:Quaternion doesn't compile, but that Second Life model may do just the trick.